# how to Continue thread

Tags: wpf

I am using a WPF user control. I should enable the button when a response comes from a socket, as I am mostly using ***layoutupdate*** when the response comes. The thread is changing and the layout is not being updated. I tried to use focus but it gives an error:

```
class.button.isEnabled = true;
```

Error:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

I tried to use a dispatcher, but I cannot achieve success:

```
userControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new Action(() => {
                    class.button.IsEnabled = true;
                    }));
```

Error:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => class.button.isEnabled = true);` doesn't work too?